# Use of "slush" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idiomatic-language

Children are playing football during rain. A child falls on the wet mud as described In the following sentence

> The boy came slushing down on the ground.

Is it common/idiomatic to use slush as a verb in this way? Because mostly on Internet I have found examples of "slush" as a noun or in some phrase like "with a slush".

Comment: It's not common, but it's understandable as a use of [onomatopoeia](https://literarydevices.net/onomatopoeia/).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/slushing

After abunch of other possible meanings there is this.

v.intr.  2. To make a splashing or slushy sound.

Similar things from Oxford Languages but I can't seem to figure out how to cite that. It is amusing that the definition has some implied onomatopoeia. "Slushing" is defined as making a sound like "slush."

It means that the boy's falling on the ground was producing a noise. Probably the ground was very wet so that water or mud was splashing around.

As to being idomatic, I'm not sure. I have not seen such used but I understood it fairly directly without having to look it up.

Comment: "As to being idiomatic, I'm not sure." I've never heard it. I suggest that @Learner avoids it.

Comment: 'making a sound like "slush."' refers back to usage 1. Partially melted snow or ice. Very few Brits don't know what that sounds like when you walk through it.